# Why is a UIAlertAction's handler required to have a parameter that references the UIAlertAction?

Tags: swift, syntax, uibutton, handler, uialertaction

I'm working with a simple button that, when pressed, runs a function I created.

Originally, I wrote the code like this:

```
func askQuestion() {
     // runs code to ask a question
}

@IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
     let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "You tapped the button.", preferredStyle: .alert)
     ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: askQuestion))
    present(ac, animated: true)
```

But that returns an error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '() -> ()' to expected argument type '((UIAlertAction) -> Void)?'
```

Which is fixed when you add the following parameter to askQuestion():

```
askQuestion(action: UIAlertAction! = nil)
```

Why does a handler method passed into the UIAlertAction require that it accept a UIAlertAction parameter? It seems like an unnecessary step, but I was thinking it might be a way to scan your code for hints that this function is triggered by a button.

Comment: You could use a single handler for multiple actions - so it would be useful to know which action is actually calling your handler

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks. this actually answers my core question but since it's a comment I can't accept it as the best answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have a single handler responsible for handling multiple actions

```
var continueAction: UIAlertAction!
var cancelAction: UIAlertAction!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    continueAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Continue", style: .default, handler: masterHandler)
    cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: masterHandler)
}

//...

 let ac = UIAlertController(title: title, message: "You tapped the button.", preferredStyle: .alert)
 ac.addAction(continueAction)
 ac.addAction(cancelAction)
```

Personally, I don't know why you might do this, but the API designers felt it was a good idea to provide you with the flexibility to design your solution which best meet your needs.

So, in most cases, while I appreciate it seems weird (especially when you can use closures), I do appreciate having the information available to make my own choices

Answer (score 1):

What if the alert has a text field in it and you need to fetch that text?

What if the same function is shared by multiple alerts and you need to know which alert this is (perfectly possible)?

What if this is a UIAlertController subclass with a property or method you need to access? (Yes I’ve done that.)

You need a reference to the alert! And you need it as an already weak reference so you don’t get a retain cycle if you’re using a trailing closure. So the action handler is given one as parameter.

Trust me, if you didn’t get a reference to the alert, sooner or later you’d find yourself in a situation where you’d be furious and stymied.

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
func askQuestion(_ action:UIAlertAction){} // ->() is the void return here
```

necessary/not `UIAlertAction` handler  has `UIAlertAction -> ()` callback so you have to implement  , sometimes you do

```
alert.addAction(UIAlertAction.......{ (action) in }
```

so it's useful to know some details about the current action like title or style

Comment: or simply `{ _ in }`

Comment: @LeoDabus sure  , but op thought it's useless